# Set top level link in Eclipse InfoCenter TOC using DITA-OT

Tags: xml, eclipse, dita, dita-ot

I am using DITA-OT to convert a set of DITA files into an Eclipse Information Center help system. The map in the input `.ditamap` file has a list of `topicrefs`. DITA-OT sets the link of the first topic in this list as the link of the top level TOC node.

The resulting TOC looks like this:

- Product 1.2.3 `links to overview.html`

  - Overview `links to overview.html`
  - ...
  - ...

As you can see, the top level entry links to the same page as its first child. What I need is the top level entry linking to a page separate from the first child:

- Product 1.2.3 `links to welcome_page.html`

  - Overview `links to overview.html`
  - ...
  - ...

How can I set the link that is within the top level TOC entry?

I suspect that this may not be possible, since this pattern of links repeated in the top level TOC entry and its first child is present in the Eclipse documentation (https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DITA-OT uses the **first `topicref` even if `toc="no"` for the TOC top level link**:

```
<map title="Product 1.2.3">
  <topicref href="welcome_page.dita" toc="no"/>
  <topicref href="overview.dita"/>
  ...
</map>
```